# Partial views in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i m working in asp.net and i want to implement partial views. i want to load .ascx page without refreshing the current page and not even url changed. can i implement it in asp.net.
if any one any link which will be useful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the AJAX support in ASP.NET, which allows you to load parts of the page asynchronously.  http://www.asp.net/ajax is probably a good place to start.